# Jenkins Plugin Development: which version of dependencies to use?

Tags: maven, jenkins

For developing a Jenkins plugin using maven, I have to define the versions of the libraries that I depend on in `pom.xml`.
How can I figure out which versions to use? Is there anything other than lengthy trial and error sessions to find a combination that maven accepts?

I Generated a plugin skeleton with

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=io.jenkins.archetypes:empty-plugin
```

I get a basic pom targeted for Jenkins 2.7.3 , which is fine with me.

I install Jenkins 2.7.3 and let it download the plugins to complete its installation.

Now I check the versions of its plugins that Jenkins picked and enter them in my POM:

```
  org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-job: 2.12.2
  org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-scm-step: 2.6
  org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps: 2.45
  org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-api: 2.27
  org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-support: 2.18
  org.jenkins-ci.plugins:scm-api: 2.2.7
```

(simplified syntax for readability)

Trying to build this, maven fails with:

```
  Rule 6: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireUpperBoundDeps failed with message:
  Failed while enforcing RequireUpperBoundDeps. The error(s) are [
  Require upper bound dependencies error for org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.10 paths to dependency are:
  +-io.jenkins.plugins:Devgate:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-job:2.12.2
     +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.10
  and
  +-io.jenkins.plugins:Devgate:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-scm-step:2.6
     +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.9
  and
  +-io.jenkins.plugins:Devgate:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps:2.45
     +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.13
  and
  +-io.jenkins.plugins:Devgate:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-api:2.27
     +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.10
  and
  +-io.jenkins.plugins:Devgate:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-support:2.18
     +-org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-step-api:2.13
  ]
```

How can I solve this? Where can I get a set of dependency versions that can coexist?